# Convert large xyz file into gridded data (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, grid, geotiff

I have a large XYZ file (300276x3, this file includes x and y coordinates (not lat/lon, but polar stereographic) and elevation z) and I'm wondering if it would be possible to convert this into a gridded dataset (n x m matrix). The xyz file can be downloaded from:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/4ae4ce51072dceef93486314d161509920191021213532/48e4ee68c17269bd6f7a72c1384b3c9a20191021213532/60b04d

and imported in matlab by:

```
AIS_SEC = importdata('AIS_SEC.xyz');
```

I tried:

```
X= XYZ(:,1);
Y= XYZ(:,2);
Z= XYZ(:,3);
xr = sort(unique(X));
yr = sort(unique(Y));
gRho = zeros(length(yr),length(xr));
gRho = griddata(X,Y,Z,xr,yr')
imagesc(gRho)

Requested 300276x300276 (671.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays
greater than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size
limit or preference panel for more information.
```

I tried:

```
% Get coordinate vectors 
    x = unique(XYZ(:,1)) ;
    y = unique(XYZ(:,2)) ;
    % dimensions of the data
    nx = length(x) ; 
    ny = length(y) ;
    % Frame matrix of grid 
    D = reshape(XYZ(:,3),[ny,nx]) ;
    % flip  matrix to adjust for plot
    H = flipud(H) ;
    % Transpose the matrix 
    H = H' ;  % Check if is required
    surf(x,y,H) ;

Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

I can now plot the nx3 file with scatter3 (see image)

```
scatter3(XYZ(:,1),XYZ(:,2),XYZ(:,3),2,XYZ(:,3)) ;
colorbar
```

But I'd like to do it with imagesc. Hence, I would like to convert the nx3 file into a nxm matrix (in raster/gridded format) and as en extra I would like it as a geotiff file for use in QGIS.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: "_I tried some things like meshgrid, but Matlab keeps telling me the resulting grid is too large_" Please show what you tried, and a small example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @rinkert I updated some things. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there... Looking at the message about array size you got, it seems likely that the result of `unique(X)` results in 300276 unique values, probably due to some noisy data.

So instead of using `griddata` with these large `X` and `Y` vectors, you can define some new ones on the domain you need:

```
% make some sample data
N = 1000;
xv = linspace(-10,10,N);
yv = linspace(-10,10,N);
[XV,YV] = meshgrid(xv,yv);
ZV = XV.^2 + YV.^2;

% make into long vectors:
X = XV(:);
Y = YV(:);
Z = ZV(:);

% make x and y vector to interpolate z
N = 50; % size of new grid
xv = linspace(min(X), max(X), N); 
yv = linspace(min(Y), max(Y), N);
[XV,YV] = meshgrid(xv,yv);

% use griddata to find right Z for each x,y pair
ZV_grid = griddata(X,Y,Z,XV,YV);

% look at result
figure(); 
subplot(211)
imagesc(ZV);
subplot(212);
imagesc(ZV_grid)
```

[image]